# Select2 dropdown search

Tags: javascript, select

Is it possible that when a user is on a dropdown, and start typing, that the dropdown can open and start searhing. As it is now, the user first has to click ENTER or SPACE.

I am using select2.4 beta 2

Comment: Version 4.0.0-beta.3

http://jsfiddle.net/xDUUg/1840/

Comment: thanks, but your example fails